# How to access blob in azure using pyspark in jupyter?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I access a BLOB in Azure using pyspark in jupyter?

**I am trying it with this Line of Code:**

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sc.textFile("wasbs://xxxxxstorage.blob.core.windows.net/media/Media.txt").count()
```

**This is the error I am getting:**

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: wasbs://xxxxxstorage.blob.core.windows.net/media/Media.txt
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you? https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/98

Comment: No, this doesn't work

Comment: Probably your path is not correct? wasbs://<blob container name>@<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/media/Media.txt